# Is there a way to make it that a twitter bot will reply to a specific username if they tweet

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy, tweets

If the user sends out a tweet, how can I get it so that the bot will automatically reply to it? For example, if I have this function that sends a reply

```
username = "someones_username"
count = 1 # I'm just doing this so that the practice code will only send to the newest tweet. In the final program, I want it so that evertime the user tweets, they get a reply

def send_reply():
    for tweet in api.user_timeline(id=username, count=count):
        try:
            tweetID = tweet.id
            api.update_status("@" + username + "hello", in_reply_to_status_id=tweetID)
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            print(e.reason)
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

How can I get it that when a user tweets, the above function runs and replies to them? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you read this documentation http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#timeline-methods
especially the part about API.user_timeline. It answers your question. You could use sinceId after getting the initial request to see if any new post have been made, and if so renewing the sinceid and replying to them.